# Помогите доработать скрипт синхронизации игровых объектов

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. Я работаю над скриптом синхронизации объектов в unet и никак не могу решить проблему гладкого передвижения объекта, данный скрипт получает от сервера местоположение объекта, все хорошо, интерполяция работает вроде как надо, но наблюдаются рывки, вместо гладкого передвижения. Может кто-то посмотрим свежим взглядом и найдет изъян в коде.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class SyncObj : NetworkBehaviour {

public NetGM_Player netGM_Player = null;
float maxRate = 0.06f; // частота отправки кадров

Vector3 lastPosition = new Vector3 (0, 100, 0);

Vector3 endPosition = new Vector3();
Quaternion endRotation = new Quaternion();
Vector3 startMarker_Position = new Vector3();
Quaternion startMarker_Rotation = new Quaternion();
float endTime = 0;
float prec=0;

float numscr = 0;

float lastSendScren = 0;

int factor = 1;

public float delta =0;

Rigidbody rig;

Vector3 oldPosServ = new Vector3();
Quaternion oldRotServ = new Quaternion();

Vector3 newPosServ = new Vector3();
Quaternion newRotServ = new Quaternion();

// client
List<ScreenTransform> _scrinsTransformPlayer = new List<ScreenTransform>();
int numScreen = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //запросить текущее положение объекта
    if (isClient) {
        CmdSyncStartPos (transform.position, transform.rotation);
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        rig.isKinematic = true;
        rig.useGravity = false;
        rig.mass = 0f;
        rig.angularDrag = 0f;
        rig.interpolation = RigidbodyInterpolation.Interpolate;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate () {
    Client ();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    ClientUpdate ();
    ServerFixedUpdate ();
}

//запросить текущую позицию объекта у сервера
[Command]
void CmdSyncStartPos(Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot)
{
    if (transform.position != pos || transform.rotation != rot) {
        RpcSendAllNewTransform (transform.position, transform.rotation, Time.time);
    }
}
[ClientRpc]
void RpcSendAllNewTransform(Vector3 newPosition, Quaternion newRotation, float time)
{
    // добавить новый кадр в очередь
    numScreen++;
    //Debug.Log ("Номер: " + numScreen + " Время: " + Time.fixedTime);
    _scrinsTransformPlayer.Add (new ScreenTransform(gameObject.GetInstanceID(), newPosition, newRotation, time, numScreen));
}

//GM_local_main объект к которому игрок имеет доступ, в данном объекте содержется синхронизированное с сервером время,
//получаемое через метод GetServerTime();
void Client()
{
    if (!isClient)
        return;


}

void ClientUpdate()
{
    if (!isClient)
        return;

    if (netGM_Player == null) {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find ("GM_local_main"); 
        if (obj != null) {
            netGM_Player = obj.GetComponent<NetGM_Player> ();
        }
    }


    if (netGM_Player != null) {

        //интерполяция
        //Если скрины есть в очереди
        if (_scrinsTransformPlayer.Count > 0)
        {

            if (SerchScreen ()) {

                startMarker_Position = transform.position;

                //конечная позиция берется из кадра
                endPosition = _scrinsTransformPlayer [0].position;

                numscr = _scrinsTransformPlayer [0].number;

                startMarker_Rotation = transform.rotation;
                endRotation = _scrinsTransformPlayer [0].rotation;
                //время к которому объект должен достичь своей точки
                endTime = _scrinsTransformPlayer [0].time;
                //удалить кадр из учереди
                    _scrinsTransformPlayer.RemoveAt (0);

            }

        }
        //рассчитываем какой процент от всего пути объект должен был сделать к текущему времени
        float test = netGM_Player.GetServerTime () + Time.fixedTime;
        prec = ((netGM_Player.GetServerTime () + Time.fixedTime - maxRate*2) - (endTime)) / (maxRate);

        Debug.Log ("процент: " + prec + " Текущее время: " + (netGM_Player.GetServerTime() + Time.fixedTime - maxRate*2) + " endTime " + endTime + " номер " + numscr);

        //интерполируем положение объекта
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (startMarker_Position, endPosition, prec);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (startMarker_Rotation, endRotation, prec);
    }

}

void ServerFixedUpdate()
{
    if (!isServer)
        return;

    if (lastSendScren == 0) {

        oldPosServ = transform.position;
        oldRotServ = transform.rotation;
        // 3 цикла: 3 * 0.2 = 0.6
        lastSendScren = 2;
        RpcSendAllNewTransform (transform.position, transform.rotation, Time.fixedTime);
    } else
        lastSendScren--;
}

// поиск подходящего кадра
bool SerchScreen()
{
    bool find = false;
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _scrinsTransformPlayer.Count; i++) {

        // текущее серверное время - задержка в 2 maxRate
        if (netGM_Player.GetServerTime () + Time.fixedTime - maxRate*2 >= _scrinsTransformPlayer [i].time 
        ){
                k = i;
                find = true;
        }
    }
    if (find)
        for (int j = 0; j < k - 1; j++) {
            _scrinsTransformPlayer.RemoveAt (0);
        }
    return find;
}
```

}

Складывается впечатление, что проблема не в этом скрипте, а в какой то особой механики Unity. 
Если посмотреть начало данного видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=co_ACWIu4XU&t то в нем как раз можно увидеть мою проблему, объект синхронизирован, но движется рывками, хотя интерполяция работает хорошо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил данную проблему заменив Vector3.lerp на Vector3.SmoothDamp и использованием UDP, правда пришлось чутка доработать обработку кадров. При использовании Смуза управление становится менее приятным, она становится более тугим, но если добавить в скрипт опережающий ввод, то смуз можно сделать меньше и управление будет нормальным.

Answer (score 0):

Умножайте на Time.deltaTime-рывков не будет)